# Call setUp method before InjectMock creation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am working on a **legacy application**, which is keeping 2 DI contexts in the same application, I want to test a class using mockito, which is having a private dependency. 
The class I want to test is in guice context, guice context has spring context as a registered bean and class looks like this :

```
@Singleton
public class A {
   @Autowired
   private B b;

   @Inject
   public A(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
   }

   //OTHER METHODS

}
```

when I try to test like this, it throws null pointer exception, as setup method is executed at the creation of class A, and getAutowireCapableBeanFactory() returns null in the constructor and calling a method on this throws null pointer exception.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

   @Mock
   private B b;

   @Mock
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   @InjectMocks
   private A a;

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
      when(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()).thenReturn( mock(AutowireCapableBeanFactory.class));
   }
}
```

please suggest any solution to this issue or any workarounds.

Comment: Hah 2 DI frameworks 1 application? Ouch.

Comment: that's not the right way I agree, its a legacy application, and that cannot be changed, I am looking for a workaround to this problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you're using constructor injection. You can take advantage of that to wire in your own mocks explicitly (instead of relying on your dependency injection framework)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext = mock(ApplicationContext.class);

    private A a = new A(applicationContext);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        when(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()).thenReturn( mock(AutowireCapableBeanFactory.class));
    }
}
```

On a side note, field injection seems to be a frowned upon practice. Setting up A to use constructor injection would not even be a workaround... rather a step in the right direction.

```
@Singleton
public class A {

    private B b;

    @Inject
    public A(ApplicationContext applicationContext, B b) {
      this.b = b;
      applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);

    }

}
```

Comment: B is a private member of A, and there was no need for setter, doing it this way will make B member in A as null

Comment: To my point about field injection. It is generally recommended to use constructor injection so that the dependencies are clearly defined and you don't need to rely on reflections (`@InjectMock`) to set your tests up

Comment: yes, that's a recommended way, I agree with you, but in my problem statement at present, it won't help. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to clarify your comment `as to B being a member in A as null.`